# How do I remove a spell "stuck" on my hand in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

The spell "Lesser Ward" is stuck on my right hand in Skyrim.  I can no longer replace it with another spell by using the GUI, and I can't unequip it either.  Using the "favorites"  hotkey, I can equip both hands to a spell and then equip another to my left hand to get a wanted spell on my right, but this is a bit cumbersome.  Since I'm a Khajiit mage, I like to have a spell in my left hand and my right hand free for attacking.

If I try to use the console to remove the spell, my right hand simply doesn't do anything.  I then can't attack, but I can't use the offending ward either.

This problem persists through saves - if I load a save from before the problem, I still have the spell in my right hand.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Should I?  If there's a way to avoid it I'd like to find it.  Reinstalling seems a little heavy-handed (though I guess it would be a solution).

Comment: your save files will remain, and this problem does sound like corrupted game data if its even happening in different saves. When did this issue start happening?

Comment: It's happened before on different installs on different computers, but this instance began yesterday.  It's well-documented occurring, but nowhere have I found an actual solution.

Comment: (Plus, re-installing is a lot of bother.)

Comment: As a test: does the problem persist through different characters?

Comment: I don't know (I only have one at the moment).  I'll get back to you in a couple hours.

Comment: Got it - in a new character, the problem is gone, but in my older saves from the original character I still have the problem.  Wow, this is confusing.

Comment: Try validating Steam files - Verify integrity of game cache

Comment: Do you have mods installed? If yes, can you include a list of them?

Comment: No mods - vanilla Skyrim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution!  After I created a character ("Test Orc", the ugliest mug known to man) to see if the glitch persisted to new characters, I loaded an old save from before the problem occurred.  Lo and behold, the glitch was gone!  It's probably because of some cache nonsense (like Alice Rees said in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem a lot and it seems to persist... if it continues, you can try equipping a sword or something in your right hand and then unequipping it, then choose a new spell.